# Need help with proof about Dedekind-infinite sets

Tags: set-theory

I am working on a formal proof on a fundamental theorem of set theory to do with cardinality. I am stuck on the following point:

Suppose $B\subsetneq A$ and we have bijection $f: B\rightarrow A$ (i.e. $A$ is Dedekind infinite).

Suppose $B\subsetneq C\subset A$. How can I prove that we must then have some bijection $g:B\rightarrow C$?

**EDIT 1**

Additionally, $\forall x (x\in A \wedge x\notin B\rightarrow \neg\exists y (y\in A \wedge f(y)=x))$

**EDIT 2**

This additional condition would seem to lead to a contradiction. Thanks to user14111 for pointing this out. I will probably need to reformulate my question. Sorry.

**EDIT 3**

It looks like $B$ need not be a proper subset of $A$ after all. Apologies for wasting readers' time. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Think that $A=\mathbb{N}$, then you get te intuition to do it in general. Is like when you prove that Dedekind infinite if and only infinite.

Comment: You can't delete a question with upvoted answers. Certainly not with two.

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK. I wondered about that. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem. You have an injection from $A$ into $C$ (the inverse of $f$) and you have an obvious injection from $C$ into $A$.

Conclude as wanted.

Comment: And once again it is exemplified that the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein Theorem is one of the most convenient results in set theory, if not in all of mathematics.

Comment: Is there no more straightforward way -- one that does not invoke of the convoluted machinery of the CBS proof?

Comment: @Dan: I don't think so. This, in a nutshell, the Cantor-Bernstein theorem itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your additional assumption leads to a contradiction.

Since $B\subsetneq A$, there is an $x$ such that $x\in A \wedge x\notin B$. Since $f: B\rightarrow A$ is a bijection, there exists $y\in B$ such that $f(y)=x$. Since $B\subset A$, we then have $y\in A \wedge f(y)=x$, contradicting the assumption that $\forall x (x\in A \wedge x\notin B\rightarrow \neg\exists y (y\in A \wedge f(y)=x))$.

From a contradiction we can get anything, in particular, a bijection $g:B\rightarrow C$.

Comment: You are right. This may be the key. Or perhaps I will need to reformulate my question. Maybe they are not really bijections as I assumed. Not sure yet. I have left out a lot of detail. Thanks in any case!